# Is there something similar to GTK+'s GtkSizeGroup in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, gtk

GTK+ has a widget called [GtkSizeGroup](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkSizeGroup.html) which is used to synchronize the sizes of widgets that don't have the same parent. Is there a similar widget in Qt?

***UPDATE*** The parents of the widgets are different. I have 2 groupboxes, and there are labels / QLineEdits inside. I'd like to line them up.

```
+-[ Group1 ]----------------------+
|              ------------------ |
| longer label |                | |
|              ------------------ |
+---------------------------------+
+-[ Group2 ]----------------------+
|       ------------------        |
| label |                |        |
|       ------------------        |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If a custom QLayout is a problem (depending on the parenting hierarchy, it might be), you could do this via an eventFilter on resizeEvent - each slave widget would install itself (or a helper) as an event filter on the master widget, and when it sees a resize event, update its own size. How good or badly this works will depend on your specific situation, however.

Comment: Huh. I thought there is something in the GUI designer I haven't noticed. But maybe I should live with that and write real code for this :(

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could create something similar with a custom [QLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html). Also see [How to Write A Custom Layout Manager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager)